# Yup conditional validation of a field to make it required if a state changes

Tags: typescript, yup

I have a state (allowBuyItNow) that is boolean. There is a field (buyItNowPriceAmountCents) in the React hook form that needs to be required if the state value is true. I am using it in when condition but it is giving error with typescript.

```
 buyItNowPriceAmountCents: yup
        .number()
        .typeError(`${translation('app.feed.item.sale.buyNow.price')} ${translation('empty_field')}`)
        .when(allowBuyItNow, {
          is: true,
          then: yup
            .number()
            .required(`${translation('app.feed.item.sale.buyNow.price')} ${translation('empty_field')}`)
            .typeError(`${translation('app.feed.item.sale.buyNow.price')} ${translation('empty_field')}`),
        }),
```

The state is not the part of the form, or the formValues do not have this state value.

```
Error: Argument of type 'boolean' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | any[]'
```

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this ?